# Process being killed mysteriously by SIGINT

Tags: linux, signals

I'm trying to discover why some of my processes are being mysteriously killed by SIGINT (I'm not pressing CTRL + C ). I tried using `strace` in a process that's receiving the SIGINT "attack" and after some time I got the attack with the following info:

```
> strace -p 61571 -e trace=signal
strace: Process 61571 attached
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=0, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

I see that `SI_USER` can mean signal sent by `kill`, `sigsend`, `raise` or `abort`. Irrelevant info for me, correct?

What about `si_pid` and `si_uid` being set to `0`? What does zero mean for these properties? The value of `SI_USER` seems to be zero. Was everything just zero-initialized?

Please let me know if more info is needed.